# azure appsettings with json file in azure cli

Tags: asp.net

When am Running below azure cli command:

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g az1xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx -n wexxx-xxx-xxx-xx --settings @appSettings.json
```

I'm getting error:

> ERROR: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\knack\knack\cli.py",
>   line 197, in invoke   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py", line 373, in execute   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\six\six.py",
>   line 693, in reraise   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py", line 347, in execute   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py", line 182, in **call**   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core__init__.py",
>   line 440, in default_command_handler   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvxpk9ku\azure-cli-appservice\azure\cli\command_modules\appservice\custom.py",
>   line 153, in update_app_settings ValueError: not enough values to
>   unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I'm trying to update the key values from JSON file.

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "keyp",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "Val_updated"
  },
  {
    "name": "key_new_via_cli",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "Val_via_cli"
  },
{
    "name": "kevp",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "Val_update"
  },
]
```

Azure Cli version : 2.0.50

Comment: I'm having the same problem and [filed a ticket on github about it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11552). Waiting for a response...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add double quotes to settings filename?

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g az1xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx -n wexxx-xxx-xxx-xx --settings "@appSettings.json"
```

Comment: Double quotes to the settings filename worked for me.